# Redirect site .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect this

```
https://www.example.com/watch?v=ilTNJoSgeF8
```

to this

```
http://www.example.com/#/watch/ilTNJoSgeF8
```

so it just need to change this `/watch?v=` into this `/#/watch/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, you can do something like this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^watch$ /#/watch/%1? [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: thats work. but if page is in https can we make to http

Comment: @ArMegatox that's a completely different issue, probably lots of examples on stack overflow